Interpreting small-scale residual values from spatial point pattern model
I'm working with a spatial point pattern dataset using spatstat in R to assess how well a fitted non-stationary Poisson point process model captures the spatial intensity of events, considering several environmental covariates (e.g., distance to features, elevation, slope, geology).
After fitting the model and computing the Pearson residuals, I'm noticing the residual map has values that are mostly close to zero, with a small range (e.g., between -0.0004 and 0.0002). I understand that residuals near zero typically suggest a good fit, but I want to ensure I'm interpreting this small scale of residuals correctly.
Does the near-zero scale of these Pearson residuals imply that the model captures the intensity structure effectively, or should I consider potential missing factors?
Code for reference:
# Model fitting
model <- ppm(my_point_pattern ~ covariate1 + covariate2 + covariate3)

# Residuals computation
res <- residuals(model, type = "pearson")
res_smoothed <- Smooth(res)
plot(res_smoothed, main = "Smoothed Pearson Residuals with Contours")
contour(res_smoothed, add = TRUE)

